# bad_alloc exception while implementing the merge sort for larger arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, mergesort, bad-alloc

I'm implementing the merge sort algorithm using C++. An exception(bad_alloc) is raised, while sorting larger arrays. Since i'm new to C++ i have no idea about how to get rid of this error. The answer i'm willing is not handling the exception, but the reason.

Here's my main method where i initially calls merge_sort function.

```
int *arr;

int main(){
        int limits[2]={10,10000000};            //numbers of elements that should be in an array at each iteration

        for(int l=0;l<sizeof(limits)/sizeof(*limits);l++){
                cout<<"\n"<<endl;
                arr=new int[limits[l]];
                for(int cnt=0;cnt<limits[l];cnt++){                             //creating the random array using random numbers
                        int temp=rand()%2147483647;
                        arr[cnt]=temp;
                }
                clock_t t;
                t=clock();
                cout<<"\nNumber of elements  :  "<<limits[l]<<endl;

                merge_sort(0,limits[l]-1);                              //calling the merge sort function
                cout<<endl;
                t=clock()-t;
                cout<<"The time taken :  "<<t<<endl;
                delete[] arr;
        }
        cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Up to 1000000 elements this works fine. I'm having the trouble when sorting the array of size 10000000.

Here's the full code for test purposes.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<limits>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
void merge_sort(int i,int j);
void merge(int i,int temp,int j);

int *arr;

//main method
int main(){
        int limits[2]={10,10000000};            //numbers of elements that should be in an array at each iteration
        for(int l=0;l<sizeof(limits)/sizeof(*limits);l++){
                cout<<"\n"<<endl;
                arr=new int[limits[l]];
                for(int cnt=0;cnt<limits[l];cnt++){                             //creating the random array using random numbers
                        int temp=rand()%2147483647;
                        arr[cnt]=temp;
                }
                clock_t t;
                t=clock();
                cout<<"\nNumber of elements  :  "<<limits[l]<<endl;

                merge_sort(0,limits[l]-1);                              //calling the merge sort function

                t=clock()-t;
                cout<<"The time taken :  "<<t<<endl;
                delete[] arr;
        }
        cin.get();
return 0;
}


//method implementing the merge sort algorithm
void merge_sort(int i,int j){
        if(i<j){
                int temp=(i+j)/2;
                merge_sort(i,temp);
                merge_sort(temp+1,j);
                merge(i,temp,j);
        }
        return;
}


//method implementing the merge algorithm
void merge(int i,int temp,int j){
        int n1=temp-i+2;                                    //calculating the sub array lengthes
        int n2=j-temp+1;
        int *L=NULL;
        int *R=NULL;
        L=new int[n1];                                      //dynamically initializing the sub left and right hand side arrays
        R=new int[n2];

        for(int x=0;x<n1-1;x++){
                L[x]=arr[i+x];
        }
        for(int y=0;y<n2-1;y++){
                R[y]=arr[temp+y+1];
        }
        L[n1-1]=numeric_limits<int>::max();                 //adding the largest possible integer to the end of each array
        R[n2-1]=numeric_limits<int>::max();
        int a=0;
        int b=0;
        for(int k=i;k<=j;k++){                              //merging the two sub arrays
                if(L[b]>R[a] ){
                        arr[k]=R[a];
                        a++;
                }
                else{
                        arr[k]=L[b];
                        b++;
                }
        }
}
```

It's better if someone can give me the reason behind this rather than a fix. Thanks!

Comment: Think about why a `bad_alloc` exception is thrown - you're out of memory. The reason you're running out of memory is because you're leaking memory in `merge`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `merge` function has a memory leak, and a very big one:

```
L = new int[n1];    
R = new int[n2];
```

The memory is never deallocated.  If you're coming from a language such as Java or C#, you see that C++ works differently.  There is no automatic garbage collection, and using `new[]` in C++ requires you use `delete[]` at some point, else you get a memory leak.

But a better solution would be to replace those lines with this:

```
#include <vector>
//...
// Remove the int *L and int *R declarations.
//
std::vector<int> L(n1);
std::vector<int> R(n2);
```

You should always think `vector` first over using `new[]/delete[]` to avoid these types of memory errors.

Once you make those changes, the program will complete, but takes a while (at least it did with Visual Studio 2013 in debug mode).

In release mode, the time took for 10000000 was 3,300 ms.

Edit:  For an experiment, I used the following code to see what would happen if the vector was moved out of the function, and just reused:

```
std::vector<int> L;
std::vector<int> R;

void merge(int i, int temp, int j){
    int n1 = temp - i + 2;  
    int n2 = j - temp + 1;

    L.resize(n1);
    R.resize(n2);
//...
}
```

So I made the vectors global.  The amount of time it took was closer to 2,000 ms, so approximately 1,000 ms faster.  The advantage is the usage of `resize` to resize the vectors as opposed to redeclaring them, or using `new[]/delete[]` multiple times.

Comment: I tried to delete the arrays L and R at the end of the merge method, but then it gave me another kind of error. can't i do the above thing using an array(an alternative with arrays and no memory leak)? except using a vactor.

Comment: Arrays are fixed in size in C++, so you cannot declare them with a runtime expression.  A vector is a safer wrapper for `new[]/delete[]`, so in essence, a vector is doing exactly what your original code was doing, only correctly.  When you say it gave you another error, what was the error?

Comment: BTW, I did a test and changed the code slightly to reuse the vector instead of redeclaring them.  A full second was removed from the time it took to sort 10000000 items (another advantage of vector is the `vector::resize` function over calling `new[]/delete[]` over and over again.)

Comment: as I remember(when i uses a dynamically initialized array and the delete[] statement) it was assertion failure... Vector thing is working fine for me. But how is the performance with "vector" over typical arrays?

Comment: @IMS I updated my comment above.  The difference can be very large if you're calling new/delete thousands of times, as opposed to arranging the code so that you get to reuse a vector.  But in general, the difference will be negligible in terms of time, if there is any difference.  The only thing vector does that would take time is initialization (if there are a lot of elements).